# Windows 7 black screen after logon for about a minute

Tags: windows-7, black-screen-of-death

Apologies if this has already been asked/answered.  I googled and only seem to be able to find posts about people having the problem where the screen *stays* black indefinitely.  Mine just goes black for about a minute then loads the desktop normally.

It's been doing this for about a week (on a w7 installation I've had for over a year)

Once the desktop loads there is absolutely nothing to tell me there is a problem. Device manager doesn't show any exclamation marks.  I have a minimal amount of startup programs (as a rule I often go through msconfig removing any bullsh*t that is added by adobe/apple etc..)

Can you suggest a way or ways to find out what is causing this delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally figured out what was causing this.

It's something that's been in place for a while but never used to be a problem.   I have two PCs connected via a crossover cable.  The main PC has a bunch of mapped network drives.  If the second PC is not switched on, the main PC will show 'could not reconnect' on these drives.

Now this never used to slow anything down,  but I just deleted all these connections, and the black-screen delay has gone away completely.

It seems like something has changed in the way windows tries to reconnect network drives... namely that it hijacks everything else and tries for a longer period before it decides it can't reconnect.

Shame,  because I liked having those connections.  I'll try recreating them but without the 'reconnect at logon' check-box checked.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll start at the beginning. Have you got the lastest drivers for all your hardware?
Has this problem manifested since a certain program / piece of hardware / update was installed?
Are all relevant updates installed?
Have you done a full Virus Scan with an up to date Virus scanner?
I know its very basic but often basic steps solve problems.

Comment: Yes I have all the latest drivers.  The most significant thing I've done around the time it began was update my graphics card drivers to the latest.  I keep my windows up-to-date with windows update.  I use windows security essentials - I haven't done a recent scan, but I am fairly sure there are no viruses.  I'll do a scan.

Comment: Have you tried rolling back the drivers for your graphics card? One nVidia card I had I had to be really carefull with the drivers for, if I got them from MS Update they sent my PC screwy and I could only get really low res and 16 colours. I always had to get them from the site.

Comment: I deliberately avoided the ones from MS update (they were older than the ones available from nvidia's website)    but to see if they are the cause I'll try rolling them back

Comment: I re-downloaded and reinstalled my graphics drivers.  they are the same drivers (160.99) but for some reason this fixed the problem.  As you suggested drivers I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Seems a bit of a freebie but I won;t complain. Thanks very much

Comment: The problem came right back on the next startup :(   back to square one.    Is there some software that can monitor a startup - to tell me what process or file is responsible for the biggest delays?   my core 2 touchsmart laptop starts up much quicker than my quad core desktop!

Comment: Could a very large users folder cause a slow startup like this?  mine's about 90gb because of films and TV.

Comment: It depends if you pull it over the network. There's one way to find out :-) Have you another drive you can move the data to?